# Change or click event of mat-button-toggle

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a mat-button-toggle-group which has 5 mat-button-toggle. I need to fire an event on the click or on the change of the val, although I prefer it be a click event.

The documentation provided [here](https://material.angular.io/components/button-toggle/api) shows there is no click event, but there is a change event.

I have tried the change event too (as shown below) , but the event is not getting triggered.

```
 <mat-button-toggle-group #group="matButtonToggleGroup" [(ngModel)]="rowAction">
  <mat-button-toggle value="raw_swift_msg" (change)="onValChange(value)" matTooltip="View Message">
    <i class="fa fa-eye" style="color:#455A64" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle value="message_comment" matTooltip="Message Comment">
    <i class="fa fa-comments" style="color:#455A64" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle value="link_trade" hasAccess id="LinkMessagePopup" matTooltip="Link Message">
    <i class="fa fa-link" style="color:#455A64" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle value="audit_trail" matTooltip="View Audit">
    <i class="fa fa-history" style="color:#455A64" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </mat-button-toggle>
   <mat-button-toggle hasAccess id="MessagePopup" value="move_message" matTooltip="Move message">
    <i class="fa fa-exchange" style="color:#455A64" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </mat-button-toggle> 
  <mat-button-toggle value="log" matTooltip="View log">
    <i class="fa fa-book" style="color:#455A64" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

In My .ts file

import {MatButtonToggleModule} from '@angular/material/button-toggle';

```
onValChange(val: string) {
 this.selectedVal = val;
}
```

How to trigger the above change function?

Comment: User a reactive form, formControl or [(ngModel)]="rowAction" to change the value, the formControl has `valueChanges` Observable that you can use

Answer (score 24, accepted):

it should be :

html:

```
 <mat-button-toggle-group #group="matButtonToggleGroup">
  <mat-button-toggle value="raw_swift_msg" (change)="onValChange($event.value)" matTooltip="View Message">
    <i class="fa fa-eye" style="color:#455A64" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle (change)="onValChange($event.value)" value="message_comment" matTooltip="Message Comment" >
    <i class="fa fa-comments" style="color:#455A64" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

component:

```
onValChange(value){
     console.log(value)
}
```

check this [working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mexdkw)

Comment: @prabhatgundepalli did you check the answer? Is there any problem?

Answer (score 16):

An easier solution to get a change event on the entire mat-button-toggle-group is to set a change event on the group, instead of each toggle button.

```
<mat-button-toggle-group (change)="onValChange($event.value)">
    <mat-button-toggle value="bold">Bold</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="italic">Italic</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="underline">Underline</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

Now you can listen to the event in your component:

```
onValChange(value) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Tangentially related, for anyone using **fastclick** to remove the 300ms delay on mobile webviews, here is what I needed to do to get the `<mat-button-toggle-group>`'s `change` event to fire.

Explanation: It appears that in a desktop browser, the mat-button-toggle's toggleIt handler (leading to the group's `change` dispatcher) is listening to the button's `click` event, but in a mobile webview, the toggleIt handler is listening to the button's `touchend` event directly. Certain mobile webviews have a built-in listener on all `touchend` events which waits 300ms to see if the mobile user is single or double clicking, then dispatches the proper `click` or `dblclick` event. Fastclick interferes with that by also listening for `touchend` events which it intercepts so that the slow webview touchendHandler is never called, and dispatches an immediate single-click event itself. However in our case, the intercepted `touchend` event also won't call toggleIt. So we **turn off the interception**, which won't hurt the time it takes for toggleIt to get called (our UX), since the webview only delays the clickHandlers, not the mat-button-toggle's direct touchendHandler.

in main.ts

```
import * as FastClick from 'fastclick';
FastClick['attach'](document.body); // tslint:disable-line:no-string-literal
```

**in myComponent.ts**

```
public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  const collection = document.getElementsByClassName('mat-button-toggle-label-content');
  Array.from(collection).forEach((eachHandlingElement: Element) => {
    eachHandlingElement.classList.add('needsclick'); // deeper element
  });
}
```

in myComponent.html

```
<mat-button-toggle-group [(ngModel)]="mySelectedTabIndex" (change)="applyMySearch()">
  <mat-button-toggle *ngFor="let eachTabTitle of myTabTitles; let eachTabIndex = index" [value]="eachTabIndex"
    [class.my-highlight]="eachTabIndex === mySelectedTabIndex" [disabled]="wantDisabled(eachTabIndex)">
    {{ eachTabTitle }}
  </mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

in myComponent.css

```
mat-button-toggle {
  flex-grow: 1; /* widen visible area */
}
mat-button-toggle ::ng-deep .mat-button-toggle-label-content {
  width: stretch; /* widen clickable area */
}
mat-button-toggle-group  {
  width: 100%;
}
.my-highlight {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: You might want to just post this in a SO post with a question that you answer yourself.