# Click not catch in y mat-button-toogle

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this button-toogle in my component :

```
<mat-button-toggle-group appearance="legacy">
  <mat-button-toggle *ngFor="let seance of tableauSeances!">
    <fa-icon icon="calendar-alt"></fa-icon>
    {{ seance.dateSeance!.format('dddd D MMMM YYYY') }}
    <fa-icon icon="check-circle" class="check" *ngIf="verifierSeanceExistante(seance)"
             (click)="onClickSeance(seance)"></fa-icon>
  </mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

All is OK (tableauSeances contain my objects, fa-icons and my date are correctly display, ..) But when I click on my button, nothing is catch : function "onClickSeance" is not reach.

If I put the function call in the mat-button-toogle element, it's the same...

But if I make a call to the same function outside of the mat-button-toogle-group group, the function is called

Do you know why click is not catch ?

**EDIT 1**

Code changed after seeing Eliseo's return

TS :

```
  clicSurUneSeance(event: MatButtonToggleChange): void {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log(event.value);
  }
```

HTML :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div *ngIf="saisonSelectionneeCalendrier && saisonSelectionneeCalendrier.id && this.verifierOptionActive()" class="row calendriers">
    <mat-button-toggle-group appearance="legacy">
      <mat-button-toggle *ngFor="let seance of tableauSeances!"
                         (change)="clicSurUneSeance($event)">
        <fa-icon icon="calendar-alt"></fa-icon>
        {{ seance.dateSeance!.format('dddd D MMMM YYYY') }}
        <fa-icon *ngIf="verifierSeanceExistante(seance)" class="check" icon="check-circle"></fa-icon>
      </mat-button-toggle>
    </mat-button-toggle-group>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT 2**

Structure of the array use in ngFor

```
    { seance: ISeance, 
selection: boolean, 
identifiant: string 
}[]
```

**EDIT 3**

I've try without ngFor in the same component. First Group not working but the second yes ... ngFor has a bug ? Perhaps it's miss something, property or value that ngFor don't initialize and disturb the group ?

```
 <mat-button-toggle-group multiple="true">
        <mat-button-toggle (change)="clicSurUneSeance($event)" *ngFor="let seancePossible of tableauSeancesPossibles!">
          <fa-icon class="calendar" icon="calendar-alt"></fa-icon>
          {{ seancePossible.seance.dateSeance!.format('dddd D MMMM YYYY') }}
          <fa-icon *ngIf="seancePossible.selection" class="check" icon="check-circle"></fa-icon>
        </mat-button-toggle>
      </mat-button-toggle-group>


      <mat-button-toggle-group multiple="true">
        <mat-button-toggle (change)="clicSurUneSeance($event)" [value]="tableauSeancesPossibles![0].seance">
          <fa-icon class="calendar" icon="calendar-alt"></fa-icon>
          {{ tableauSeancesPossibles![0].seance.dateSeance!.format('dddd D MMMM YYYY') }}
          <fa-icon *ngIf="tableauSeancesPossibles![0].selection!" class="check" icon="check-circle"></fa-icon>
        </mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle (change)="clicSurUneSeance($event)" [value]="tableauSeancesPossibles![1].seance">
          <fa-icon class="calendar" icon="calendar-alt"></fa-icon>
          {{ tableauSeancesPossibles![1].seance.dateSeance!.format('dddd D MMMM YYYY') }}
          <fa-icon *ngIf="tableauSeancesPossibles![1].selection!" class="check" icon="check-circle"></fa-icon>
        </mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle (change)="clicSurUneSeance($event)" [value]="tableauSeancesPossibles![2].seance">
          <fa-icon class="calendar" icon="calendar-alt"></fa-icon>
          {{ tableauSeancesPossibles![2].seance.dateSeance!.format('dddd D MMMM YYYY') }}
          <fa-icon *ngIf="tableauSeancesPossibles![2].selection!" class="check" icon="check-circle"></fa-icon>
        </mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle (change)="clicSurUneSeance($event)" [value]="tableauSeancesPossibles![3].seance">
          <fa-icon class="calendar" icon="calendar-alt"></fa-icon>
          {{ tableauSeancesPossibles![3].seance.dateSeance!.format('dddd D MMMM YYYY') }}
          <fa-icon *ngIf="tableauSeancesPossibles![3].selection!" class="check" icon="check-circle"></fa-icon>
        </mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle (change)="clicSurUneSeance($event)" [value]="tableauSeancesPossibles![4].seance">
          <fa-icon class="calendar" icon="calendar-alt"></fa-icon>
          {{ tableauSeancesPossibles![4].seance.dateSeance!.format('dddd D MMMM YYYY') }}
          <fa-icon *ngIf="tableauSeancesPossibles![4].selection!" class="check" icon="check-circle"></fa-icon>
        </mat-button-toggle>
      </mat-button-toggle-group>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change or click event of mat-button-toggle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51105974/change-or-click-event-of-mat-button-toggle)

Comment: Yes and no. In fact, Eliséo answer and yours work well, but for some reason that I don't know, it works for me on Stackblitz but not on my intelliJ. I am checking the versions of my modules ...

Comment: Well I don't see ... my @angular/core is in 11.2.7 and my @angular/material is in 11.2.13.

Without the ngFor, it works but with the ngFor, nothing happens (no interception of the click and no change of visual state of the button) ... while it's OK on stackblitz! The only difference is that I am there in @angular/core is in 12.2.2 ...

I really don't understand why ... if you have a lead, I'm interested!

Comment: I had an example on EDIT 3

Answer (score 0):

See the [API](https://material.angular.io/components/button-toggle/api#MatButtonToggleGroup)

In the docs you see that there're a  `@Output()change: EventEmitter<MatButtonToggleChange>` that belongs to the `MatButtonToggleGroup`

What's mean this? that you can write some like

```
<mat-button-toggle-group (change)="yourFunction($event)">
  ...
</mat-button>
```

See the `(change)` -the name of the property Output- and how pass the argument in using `$event` -$event is a reserved word that Angular use in the .html and it's used always in the .html

You function receive a variable of type `MatButtonToggleChange` -see that is the same type in the definition is the EventEmitter. If you see the class `MatButtonToogleChange` you see that is an object with a property "value", so you can use

```
  yourFunction(event: MatButtonToggleChange)
  {
    console.log(event.value)
  }
```

NOTE. If the only you need is give value to a variable you take another approach, that is use, [(ngModel)] in the way

```
<mat-button-toggle-group [(ngModel)]="myvariable">
  ...
</mat-button>

{{myvariable}}
```

Or use in ReactiveForms

**Update** but (Always there a but).. you need give "value" to the toogle-buttons

```
<mat-button-toggle-group (change)="yourFunction($event)">
    <mat-button-toggle *ngFor="let seance of tableauSeances!"
            <!--see the "value"-->
            [value]="seance">
       <fa-icon icon="calendar-alt"></fa-icon>
       {{ seance.dateSeance!.format('dddd D MMMM YYYY') }}
       <fa-icon *ngIf="verifierSeanceExistante(seance)" 
           icon="check-circle" class="check"></fa-icon>
   </mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

Comment: I better understand how to assign the method to the event. I am new to Angular and my English needs to be improved! Thanks Eliséo

So, I have taken your feedback into account, but it doesn't change anything (see my code in the EDIT above), I still don't fit into my "click" function

Comment: PS : I don't just need to put value in variable because I have to do many actions in the back in this function

Comment: It's seems link to the ngFor statement... If i put button-toggle "fixed" (without ngFor), it's OK ....

Comment: @Broshet, see that you need give "value" to the `mat-button-toggle` (I update the answer)

Comment: I'm sorry but no more action .... for information, "seance" is an object (and not a string or number). I try to put a different value (seance.identifiant who is a different string  for each item) in "value" field but nothing changed ...

Comment: In addition to not executing the function, when i click on a button, the button does not change style (just when mouse is over .!) ...

Comment: What a mystery! On stackblitz, my code works .... I'll keep looking!
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tltpgp?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: @Broshet, try put the (change) in **the mat-group-toogle** instead of in the mat-button-toggle, (perhafs there're differences between @angular/material.11.2.13 and @angular/material.12.2.2) -you can in your stackblitz edit the package.json to change the versions of material to check it-

Comment: Thanks, I have try both but it's the same. I'll test update package.json (or downgrade !) in stackblitz